# matlab help: code ain't working, don't understand the error

Tags: matlab

wrote the following code, but it ain't working.
get this error:

> Error: File: Untitled1.m Line: 7 Column: 23
>   ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

and this is the script:

```
R=3;
R1=7;
r1=0:0.01:R;
r2=R:0.01:R1;
r3=R1:0.1:10;
xvec=0:0.01:10;
yvec(r1)=(R/(r1)^2).*(exp((r1)/R)((r1)^2-2*R(r1)+2*R^2)-2*R^2);
yvec(r2)=(R^3/(r2)^2).*(e-2);
yvec(r3)=0;
figure(1);
plot(xvec,yvec);
```

Comment: Please read the first section of "getting started" which is included with Matlab.  It sounds like you are coming at this from Mathematica.  That is not helpful.  You need to assume you know nothing, and then learn it from the Matlab documentation.

Comment: The index of an array must be always an integer larger than zero. So, you cannot use: `yvec(r1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you were trying to do:

```
R = 3;
R1 = 7;
xvec1 = 0:0.01:R;
xvec2 = R:0.01:R1;
xvec3 = R1:0.1:10;
yvec1 = (R ./ xvec1.^2) .* (exp(xvec1/R) .* (xvec1.^2 - 2*R*xvec1 + 2*R^2) - 2*R^2);
yvec2 = (R^3 ./ xvec2.^2) * (1e-2);
yvec3 = zeros(size(xvec3));
figure(1);
xvec = [xvec1 xvec2 xvec3];
yvec = [yvec1 yvec2 yvec3];
plot(xvec,yvec);
```

Like dustincarr wrote, you should read the basics section of MATLAB's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) to get an idea of how to write [expressions with indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).